# Create @login_required like function for used Form(Modelform). So that User can't access confidential url without login-by typing just url?

Tags: python, django, function, authentication, login-required

I know that I can use @login_required but it is only used when we store user in **User** But in my case I stored model in form So it is not working for me. Also my created user is not getting authenticated when I use user.is_authenticated So I need custom login_required decorator which can be use to stop anyone from accessing direct url (confidential URl which are only accessed when you Login).

**forms.py**

```
class usrForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(initial=123)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','email','password','position')


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(usrForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['position'].empty_label = "Select"

class usrChange(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('username','password')
        widgets= {
            'password' : forms.PasswordInput(),
            }

class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('username','password')
        widgets= {
            'password' : forms.PasswordInput(),
            }
```

**models.py**

```
class Position(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**views.py**

```
def user_list(request):
    
        context = {'user_list' : Person.objects.all()}
        
        return render(request, "usr_list.html", context)

    
        
    
def user_chnged_list(request):
    form = usrForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {'user_list' : Person.objects.all()}
    
    return render(request, "usr_list.html", context)       




def user_form(request, id=0):


    
    
    if request.method == "GET":
        if id ==0:
            form = usrForm(initial={'password': 123})  # register 
            
        else:
            auser = Person.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = usrForm(instance=auser) #update
            
        return render(request, "usr_form.html",{'form': form})

    else:
        if id == 0:
            form = usrForm(request.POST , initial={'password': 123}) # register
           
        else:
            auser = Person.objects.get(pk=id) #update
            form = usrForm(request.POST,instance=auser)
             
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        
            
        return redirect('login')


 
def user_delete(request,id):
    auser = Person.objects.get(pk=id)
    auser.delete()
    return redirect('list')


def user_login(request):
    
    form = loginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = loginForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password=form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            i = Person.objects.filter(username=username,password=password).exists()
            user = {'user_list' : Person.objects.filter(username=username,password=password)}
            
            
            
            if i == True:
                j = Person.objects.filter(username=username, position_id = 1).exists()
                if j == True:
                   
                    return redirect('list')
                
                return render(request,"usr_wlc.html", user )
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password!')
            
                
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'usr_login.html',context)


def user_detail(request,id):
    auser = Person.objects.get(pk=id) 
    form = usrChange(request.POST,instance=auser)    
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return redirect('login')


def user_logout(request):
    return redirect('/')



def user_change(request,id):
    auser = Person.objects.get(pk=id) #update
    form = usrChange(request.POST,instance=auser)
    
    return render(request, "usr_chnge.html",{'form': form})
```

Comment: Why don't you use Django's default user model?

Comment: I need to use Form for some functionality apart from just login, logout which can't be applicable if I use default user model

Comment: Seems like you are mistaken, you can do login, logout with the default user model. You may have to extend the person model with the AbstractUser model in your scenario. read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/